# How to use remote config to deactivate a mobile app

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

We are looking to use Firebase Remote Config to be able to set a remote config setting which when retrieved from the Firebase SDK, will cause the application to deactivate the current user's session.

Our process flow is:

1. User orders a rented device from our online eshop
2. User collects the device prior to the event/conference
3. User can use the app

However, sometimes the wrong device is handed out to the wrong user, so we would like the ability to from our web admin software, to use the REST API to set the remote config to deactivate=true. Then the device will fetch this value and if it receives deactivate=true then it will sign the user out.

According to the docs:

> Note: Throttling is done from within the SDK. An app can fetch a maximum of 5 times in a 60 minute window before the SDK begins to throttle and returns FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchThrottledException.

So this means we can only check once every 12 minutes if the device has been deactivated? If the user has the wrong device this can lead to lots of data that needs to be moved around in the database, so ideally we would like a much smaller fetch time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 12 minutes is the smallest time interval in which you can fetch again - as of now.

If you want a more realtime response, i would suggest using Firebase RTDB which gets sync'd to all devices in realtime.

Also, delivering values set per user can be done with conditions in Remote Config - but assuming you will have thousands & millions of users - doing this via remote config conditions is not the optimal way. You should explore RTDB.